# BIOS Save Changes without Resetting Computer

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, bios

I opened my BIOS on my Windows machine and I made a few changes like disabling overclocking, changing the preferred boot drive to the SSD, and disabling wake from USB. However, when I try to exit, the only option I get is to save and reset. I want to save my BIOS settings without resetting my computer to factory settings. How can I do this?

ps.The BIOS I have shows Aptio Setup - American Megatrends International, LLC. 2020. The computer I have is a Gateway Creator Series with an Intel CPU.

Comment: I have seen UI that refers to a reboot as "reset" in the past.  **In the past BIOS configurations typically specifically indicate default settings will be restored.**  I doubt that is the case if you are making configuration changes, if the default settings are being restored, it would specifically indicate that.  **Like all configuration changes you should take note of your current settings before you confirm your changes.**

Answer (score 0):

'Save and Reset' means save BIOS settings and restart the machine. It will not remove your data.